# unchecked expected primary expression error solidity ver 0.8.0

Tags: solidity, remix

I got the code

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract AddOverflow {

    uint256 public  a = 1;     
    uint256 public  b = 2;     
    uint256 public  c; 
   
    function add() public returns (uint256) {
        c = unchecked {a + b};
        return c;
    }
  
}
```

when I compile it using Remix it gives the error:

```
Parser error: expected primary expression.
```

The problem is with the use of unchecked.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/control-structures.html?#checked-or-unchecked-arithmetic) for guidance, it looks like you won't be able to do variable assignment inside the `unchecked` block. You could do something like this:

```
function subUnchecked(uint256 a, uint b) view public returns(uint256) {
    unchecked { return a - b ;}
}
```

While this doesn't save the result in a variable, you could save the result of the function call in a variable:

```
function callUnchecked(uint256 a, uint256 b) public {
    c = subUnchecked(a, b);
}
```

Which will set `c` to the max value of `uint256`.